# Adding IP address in kubernetes deployment file

Tags: linux, kubernetes, ip, kubectl

I want to replace the IP_ADDRESS environment variable in my kubernetes deployment file, I was earlier doing so by using the jenkins post build actions by running the following commands

```
 IP_ADDRESS=$(ip addr | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep ^20.* || ip addr | grep -Eo 'inet (addr:)?([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep -Eo '([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*' | grep ^172.16.*)
sed -i "s/\${IP_ADDRESS}/$IP_ADDRESS/g" /home/jenkins/kubernetes/internal-tools/deployment.yml
```

How can I configure the IP address correctly in my deployment file without using jenkins post build actions

snippet of my yaml file

```
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: TZ
          value: PST
        - name: spring.profiles.active
          value: devvm
        - name: jasypt.encryptor.password
          value: CProSafAe9tL
        - name: prop.type
          value: default
        - name: Automation_base_url   
          value: http://${IP_ADDRESS}:8484/
```

I tried using config maps, postStart commands to fetch and replace the IP addresses but it's not working